# Troubleshooting JS and FF onclick issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick

I am hopeful that someone can look at my code and let me know where it's failing in FF. Basically, the onclick function is not firing. Here is the JS:

```
function clear_field(field) {
            if (field.value==field.defaultValue) {
                    field.value=''
            }
    }
function calsq(form) {
 var tonf = 0.010000000000000002; // cubic feet to tons
 var cyards = 0.037;
 var rwunit = eval(fill.rwunit.value); //ft or in
 var rwidth = eval(fill.rwidth.value); //quantity
 var rwv = (rwidth) / (rwunit); // value now in feet
 var rlunit = eval(fill.rlunit.value); //ft or in
 var rlength = eval(fill.rlength.value); //quantity
 var rlv = (rlength) / (rlunit); // value now in feet
 var rthick = eval(fill.rthick.value); //quantity
 var rtv = (rthick) / 12; // value now in feet
 var rcir = 0; // factor 1728 cubic inches
 var rcyr = 0; // factor 27 cubic yards

 fill.rcyr.value = Math.round(((rwv) * (rlv) * (rtv) * (cyards)) * 10000) / 10000; // value now in cubic yards
}
```

And here is the form:

```
<form name="fill">
  <input name="rcyr" type="text" value="0" size="10" maxlength="8" readonly="readonly" id="soil_total" />
  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
      <td align="right"> <p>width </p></td>
      <td><input name="rwidth" type="text" class="values" onfocus="clear_field(this)" value="0" /></td>
      <td><select name="rwunit">
          <option value = "1" selected="selected">Feet </option>
          <option value = "12">Inches </option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"> <p>length </p></td>
      <td><input name="rlength" type="text" class="values" onfocus="clear_field(this)" value="0" /></td>
      <td><select name="rlunit">
          <option value = "1" selected="selected">Feet </option>
          <option value = "12">Inches </option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p>depth</p></td>
      <td colspan="2"><select name="rthick">
          <option value = "2">2 Inches</option>
          <option value = "4">4 Inches</option>
          <option value = "6" selected="selected">6 Inches</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="rcmunit" value = "2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="javascript:calsq('fill')" src="soil_calculator/images/soil_calculate.png" value="calc" />
</form>
```

All other browsers fire the event and calculate the total, but Firefox does not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED**

A great many thanks for all the advice and suggestions. Below is the working code.

```
function calsq(form) {
var tonf = 0.010000000000000002; // cubic feet to tons
var cyards = 0.037;
var rwunit = +document.forms.fill.rwunit.value; //ft or in
var rwidth = +document.forms.fill.rwidth.value; //quantity
var rwv = (rwidth) / (rwunit); // value now in feet
var rlunit = +document.forms.fill.rlunit.value; //ft or in
var rlength = +document.forms.fill.rlength.value; //quantity
var rlv = (rlength) / (rlunit); // value now in feet
var rthick = +document.forms.fill.rthick.value; //quantity
var rtv = (rthick) / 12; // value now in feet
var rcir = 0; // factor 1728 cubic inches
var rcyr = 0; // factor 27 cubic yards
document.forms.fill.rcyr.value = Math.round(((rwv) * (rlv) * (rtv) * (cyards)) * 10000) / 10000; // value now in cubic yards
```

}

and the form:

```
<form name="fill">
  <input name="rcyr" type="text" value="0" size="10" maxlength="8" readonly="readonly" id="soil_total" />
  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">

      <td align="right"> <p>width </p></td>
      <td><input name="rwidth" type="text" class="values" onfocus="clear_field(this)" value="0" /></td>
      <td><select name="rwunit">
          <option value = "1" selected="selected">Feet </option>
          <option value = "12">Inches </option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"> <p>length </p></td>
      <td><input name="rlength" type="text" class="values" onfocus="clear_field(this)" value="0" /></td>
      <td><select name="rlunit">
          <option value = "1" selected="selected">Feet </option>
          <option value = "12">Inches </option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p>depth</p></td>
      <td colspan="2"><select name="rthick">
          <option value = "2">2 Inches</option>
          <option value = "4">4 Inches</option>
          <option value = "6" selected="selected">6 Inches</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="rcmunit" value = "2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <img src="soil_calculator/images/soil_calculate.png" width="160" height="43" alt="Calculate Volume" onclick="calsq('document.forms.fill')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error? Check the error console. Btw. you don't need the label `javascript:` there.

Comment: Most of the lines in your function are completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using `fill` isn't a functional way to refer to the form in FF. See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/yLELV/2/ for an example.

- The `Click 1` button tries to reference `fill`; it works in Chrome but fails in FF.
- The `Click 2` button refers to `document.forms.fill`, and works in both FF and Chrome.

As others have pointed out, I'm not sure this is the only problem in your script, but it's definitely going to die with `fill is not defined` in FF.

As an aside, I see a lot of similar questions on SO, and my first question is always, why aren't you using a framework library? If you want to do *any* kind of DOM manipulation, look into [jQuery](http://jquery.org), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) - there's no need to deal with this kind of problem yourself, when all of the frameworks have solved it in really reliable ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will fix the problem but here are some first steps to consider:

You don't need to put `javascript:` in the `onclick`.

Replace all the `eval(...)` by something like `rwunit = +fill.rwunit.value;` it will convert them in numbers. And make the promise to all of us here that never, ever, you will use `eval` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It will help you debug your javascript in firefox.